# Numerical integral becomes worse as I increase precision

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I am seeing something quite weird. I have defined the following function

```
a=0.602;
fun[b_,prec_,rec_] := NIntegrate[
SetPrecision[Sin[x*b]/(x*b)*1/(1 - Log[1/(b*x)*E^(5/6)]/Log[1/(b*a)]),prec + 1], 
{x, 0,SetPrecision[E^(5/6)*a, prec+1],\[Infinity]},
WorkingPrecision -> prec, MinRecursion -> rec, MaxRecursion -> rec,
Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
```

That is, it is a numerical integral of a function that has a singularity in the integration path. Thus I specify the integration method PrincipalValue and I specify which is the location of the singularity. I try to evaluate the function

```
fun[0.1, 10, 3]
```

> 26.03451166

All seems to work fine. No warning messages. Nonetheless, I increase the working precision and the recursions

```
fun[0.1, 40, 5]
```

and I get warning messages indicating the the precision of the argument function is less than working precision (even though I set the precision of the integrand bigger that the working precision), and a nother warning message indicating that I didn't reach the prescribed accuracy after 5 recursive bisections near x=1.22057867207331034738005419708897996189157090393471338380469626587864\
441884580137263344087*10^-6

Moreover I get a different result for the integral

> 42.56941146926911600003007484227639880956

The issue continues to be there if I keep increasing prec and rec. What is going on?

Comment: Parameter a is undefined! Do you want to increase the precision of NIntegrate ?

Comment: You should read about `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` when used  in `NIntegrate`...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann typo. a is defined now

Comment: Exact values have `infinty` precision.It's better to use them.Try `a = 602/1000; 
fun1[b_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Sin[x*b]/(x*b)*1/(1 - Log[1/(b*x)*E^(5/6)]/Log[1/(b*a)]), {x, 0, 
   E^(5/6)*a, \[Infinity]}, WorkingPrecision -> 200, 
  Method -> "PrincipalValue"]; fun1[1/10]`